# how to install websocket++ dependencies?

Tags: 12.10, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to develop websocket applications in c++.

I've chosen to use websocket++ since it's a no-nonsense `#include` that doesn't try to fallback to ajax and could potentially be used with any other `#include`.

I'm not too sure exactly what packages are required to take full advantage of websocket++.

Please show me the name of these packages except the boost libraries which I'm pretty sure can be installed with `libboost-all-dev`.

Here's the list https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/wiki/Building-a-program-with-websocketpp:

```
Library Required for
boost_system    Builds that use ASIO or build environments without std::error_code
boost_regex Build environments without std::regex
boost_random    Client role only, build environments without std::random
libcrypto   Required for TLS socket component
libssl  Required for TLS socket component
libz    Required for compression extension support
libpthread  Required on posix for thread support
librt   Required on posix for high resolution timer support (some examples)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

librt, libpthread, and libz should be included by a base Ubuntu install. It is likely that libcrypto and libssl are as well. What will not be installed by default are the development headers. Packages build-essential and libssl-dev should cover most, if not all of it.

Also keep in mind that the boost versions installed by apt lag the boost.org releases by over a year. 12.10 includes boost from Nov 2011, 13.04 will include boost from Feb 2012.

Due to some more extensive recent changes to the boost libraries to align them with C++11, there may be some feature limitations or workarounds necessary if you are not supplying your own more recent build of boost.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for your great help with this!

Comment: Details based upon zaphoyd's answer here: https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/wiki/Setup-0.3X-on-Ubuntu-12.10